# Find observations in which both columns are NaN and replace them with 0 in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Here is a dataframe

```
    a    b    c   d

    nan  nan  3   5
    nan  1    2   3
    1    nan  4   5
    2    3    7   9
    nan  nan  2   3
```

I want to replace the observations in both columns 'a' and 'b' where both of them are NaNs with 0s. Rows 2 and 5 in columns 'a' and 'b' have both both NaN, so I want to replace only those rows with 0's in those matching NaN columns.

so my output must be

```
    a    b    c   d

    0    0    3   5
    nan  1    2   3
    1    nan  4   5
    2    3    7   9
    0    0    2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean series based on the conditions on columns a/b, and then use `loc` to modify corresponding columns and rows:

```
df.loc[df[['a','b']].isnull().all(1), ['a','b']] = 0

df
#     a   b c   d
#0  0.0 0.0 3   5
#1  NaN 1.0 2   3
#2  1.0 NaN 4   5
#3  2.0 3.0 7   9
#4  0.0 0.0 2   3
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df.a.isnull() & df.b.isnull(), ['a','b']] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a easier builtin function in Pandas, but this one should work.

```
df[['a', 'b']] = df.ix[ (np.isnan(df.a)) & (np.isnan(df.b)), ['a', 'b'] ].fillna(0)
```

Actually the solution from @Psidom much easier to read.